# Dealing with escaped forward slashes in JSON responses from Spring REST

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot to build a RESTful API. I'm experiencing a problem generating the the JSON response that the client is expecting. The client expects that forward slashes ("/") will be escaped with a backslash (i.e. "/"). Specifically something like this:

```
http:\/\/restcontroller-elasticbeanstalk.com\/api\/test\/browser
```

The code I have is

```
    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"));          
    return new HttpEntity<Object>(jsonResponse, headers);
```

Replacing the `"/"` in the string with `"\/"`, the output becomes `"\\/"`, it appears that Jackson is adding in the extra backslash, however there appears to be no setting that will turn this off.

`jsonResponse` contains

```
{
    "-default-": {
        "repositoryId": "-Nitrogen-",
        "repositoryName ": "-nitrogen-",
        "repositoryDescription ": "Proof of Concept",
        "vendorName ": "Nitrogen",
        "productName": "Nitrogen Repository Service",
        "productVersion": "0.0.1 (poc-b1)",
        "principalIdAnonymous": "guest",
        "principalIdAnyone": "WORLD",
        "repositoryUrl": "http://restcontroller-elasticbeanstalk.com/api/test/browser",
        "rootFolderUrl": "http://restcontroller-elasticbeanstalk.com/api/test/browser/root",
        "rootFolderId": "a344e048-3345-42de-85e6-f9d81e778e8e",
        "latestChangeLogToken": null
    }
}
```

It does have to be a JSON response as this is only a small part of a larger response. Have I missed something?

Comment: It looks like you are sending the String value from your response. Can you post the exact JSON response (key-value) ?

Comment: Apologies simplified the question too much I have edited the question, it's still simplified but hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: Probably the Jackson is adding escape character(\) for '\' while marshalling. I'm not sure this will work, but can you try to with '\\/' while setting the url in your Java class?